# How to use ThreeJS with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I want to use threeJS, so i install it with npm i three --save. I followed basic tutorial in threeJS documentation but i got an error.

```
  mounted () {
    this.initThree();
  },
  methods: {
    initThree() {
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: document.getElementById( "background" ), alpha: true, antialias: true } );
      this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

      let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
      let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
      this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      this.scene.add( this.cube );

      this.camera.position.z = 5;
      this.animate()

    },

    animate() {

      this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
      requestAnimationFrame( this.animate() );

    }
  }
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: I think you need to initialize three in your main.js.  Not in the component.  Maybe concider https://github.com/fritx/vue-threejs

Comment: I have no problem to initialize threejs but when i use recursive function. Your link can maybe resolve my problem, I will try it, thank's

Comment: where and how did you import/declare your three module ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not related to VueJS /ThreeJs, you should simply fix this line :

```
requestAnimationFrame( this.animate() );
```

It should be :

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
```

Please read more about callback : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

EDIT: You can try TroisJS, easy ThreeJS integration with VueJS : https://github.com/troisjs/trois

Comment: Thank's It work's, but can you explain me why i have to remove brackets

Comment: Because with brackets, animate() is call immediatly, without brackets it will be called by requestAnimationFrame. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function